# Extract tar.gz file from pig script

Tags: apache-pig, tar, hue

I want to extract a file from a tar.gz file from my pig script but :

When i use grunt:

```
grunt> sh tar xzvf /root/input/file.tar.gz \-\-wildcards '*AppSession*' \-\-directory /root/output/
```

The desired file is extracted in the input directory not in the output

When i use Hue pig editor :

```
sh tar xzvf /root/input/file.tar.gz \-\-wildcards \'*AppSession*\' -C /root/output/
```

I get this error:

> 2015-12-23 17:51:20,031 [uber-SubtaskRunner] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 2997: Encountered
>   IOException. java.io.IOException: sh command 'tar xzvf
>   /root/input/file.tar.gz --wildcards
>   *AppSession* -C /root/output' failed. Please check output logs for details

Comment: When using Hue, the script will be executed somewhere in the cluster, so your local file is not going to be there. You should put it in the distributed cache of the Pig script or in HDFS.

Comment: @Romain and why the option `--directory` or `-C` not working in grunt ?